# How to add pause in Google Text to Speech?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to use Google Cloud text to speech module, and I can convert a text to audio using below code. But I am unable to add breaks in the code, like a pause of 5 sec. I have added tags for break in my **synthesis_input variable**. Can anyone help me with that?

```
import os
from google.cloud import texttospeech

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="G:\service-account-key.json"

client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text="<speak>You know that facebook is a place where millions of people share their thoughts. <break time="10s"/> Today I am going to discuss 10 amazing things shared by people on facebook.</speak>")
voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code='en-IN',name="en-IN-Wavenet-C",ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE)

audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3
)
response = client.synthesize_speech(
input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
)
with open("output.mp3", "wb") as out:
# Write the response to the output file.
out.write(response.audio_content)
print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

Comment: Hi @Abhishek dot py, I hope I addressed your question. If yes, please consider accepting and upvoting. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The `<break time="10s"/>` tag in the SSML (Speech Synthesis Markup Language) input for Google Cloud Text-to-Speech does not seem to be working in the provided code.

One workaround is to use the `sleep` function from the `time` library to add a pause between audio segments.

Here's an updated code:

```py
import os
import time
from google.cloud import texttospeech

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="G:\service-account-key.json"

client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

texts = [
    "You know that facebook is a place where millions of people share their thoughts.", 
    "Today I am going to discuss 10 amazing things shared by people on facebook."
]

voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='en-IN',
    name="en-IN-Wavenet-C",
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE
)

audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3
)

with open("final_output.mp3", "wb") as out:
    for text in texts:
        synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=text)
        response = client.synthesize_speech(
            input=synthesis_input, 
            voice=voice, 
            audio_config=audio_config
        )
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        time.sleep(5)

print('Audio content written to file "final_output.mp3"')
```

Here, the text is split into two separate elements in a list `texts`. Then, each text is passed to `synthesis_input` in a loop, and a `sleep` function is used to add a pause of 5 seconds between the two audio segments.

Comment: thanks. However, the pause is only small. Even if I put 50 seconds in time.sleep, I see only 1 second pause between lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
import os
import time
from google.cloud import texttospeech 
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()


synthesis_inputs = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(ssml= "<speak> You know that facebook is a place where millions of people share their thoughts <break time='5000ms'/> Today I am going to discuss 10 amazing things shared by people on facebook.</speak>")


voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code='en-IN',name="en-IN-Wavenet-C",ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE)


audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3
)
response = client.synthesize_speech(
input=synthesis_inputs, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
)
with open("output.mp3", "wb") as out:
   out.write(response.audio_content)


print('Audio content written to file "final_output.mp3"')
```

You can add pause between  sentences by using `ssml`(Speech Synthesis Markup Language). For more information you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml).